# Controlling a combobox element in IE with VBA

Tags: internet-explorer, automation

Im trying to automate a data dump from a website using excel/VBA, i am stuck on trying to select an option from a combobox. I have used DOM explorer to find its class name and id but nothing works.

Here is the info from the DOM explorer:

`<select class="rccontrol" id="hyperfindid" rccinfo="headerParam:Query_Name">`

I have tried using:

`.document.getElementById("hyperfindid") ' This does not return an object
.document.getElementByClassName("rccontrol") ' This returns an object but i cant do anything with it?`

I just want to be able to select from this combo box

Can someone give me some idea?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code to use the getElementsByClassName or getElementbyId method to get the select element:

```
Public Sub ClickTest()    
    Dim  ie As Object         
    Dim item As Object    
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "<website url>"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set item = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("rccontrol")(0)

        'Default selected value
        expCcy = "saab"

        For Each o In item             
            'print the value and innerText to check the value.
            'Debug.Print o.Value
            'Debug.Print o.innerText

            If o.Value = expCcy Then
                o.Selected = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        'we could also use the following code to find the select element. 
        'ie.Document.getElementbyId("hyperfindid").Focus
        'ie.Document.getElementbyId("hyperfindid").selectedIndex = 2

        'if the select elements have javascript change event, we could use the following code to trigger the javascript change event
        'ie.Document.getElementbyId("list").FireEvent ("onchange")
    End With
   Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

The website resource as below:

```
<select class="rccontrol" id="hyperfindid">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try tomorrow at work it's been driving me crazy